# How to add insert tab to the insert/edit image plugin in the tinyMCE to insert image from the desktop?

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE plugin, but for the insert/edit image plugin, it doesn't allow me to add an image from the desktop. 
I don't want image to upload on the server but want to display in the editor, so i want to add an image insert in the insert/image plugin.
How can i achive this. 
While this thing can be done in the on line tinyMCE editor's demo.
please help me with this, please gimme some guide lines or credible links to achieve this.

Comment: Is there any way to make it using java script, i don't want to upload to server, just i want image to display the text area of editor.

Comment: Could some body help me with this

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a cost-free way to upload files from your own computer (which I assume is what you mean by desktop) you can use http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager/ to achieve this. I have successfully integrated this in my own envirnonment almost hassle-free (which any other free plugin couldn't achieve ;)). Their own solution is propietary (I think), but Ajax File Manager works just as good.

I use it for PHP but I think supports ASP also.

EDIT: Looks like it doesn't support ASP after all :|

Comment: I need to convert whole page, AjaxFilemanager.php to aspx extention page?

Comment: Now that I look at it, it seems that the plugin doesn't support ASP at all, I must have mixed it up with another plugin :(

Comment: You might want to tri this one instead: http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/TinyMCE-Image-Upload-Plugin-for-ASPNET.aspx I Have no experience with it but it seems simple to install